# Python 2 subprocess arguments error under Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to do a Mac version of a program that runs fine under Windows, using python 2.7.  Under Mac (OS X El Capitan running in VirtualBox), it fails because the arguments I pass to the shell are not recognized properly.

Original code:

```
for item in source_files:

    # core process
    output = sub.Popen(["mhl", "verify", "-vv", "-f", item, ">", text_report],
                       shell=True,
                       stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       stderr=sub.PIPE)
    stdout_value, stderr_value = output.communicate()
```

Under Mac only the 'mhl' argument is recognized so I tried this:

```
sub.Popen(['mhl verify -vv -f', item, '>', text_report]
```

Now the command works but the item (a .mhl file) is not recognized so I tried this:

```
sub.Popen(['mhl verify -vv -f', '/Users/simon/Documents/Documents.mhl', '>', text_report]
```

and this:

```
sub.Popen(['mhl verify -vv -f', r'/Users/simon/Documents/Documents.mhl', '>', text_report]
```

Same results, it tells me a mhl file should follow the '-f' argument. If I add the item directly to the first argument it works fine:

```
sub.Popen(['mhl verify -vv -f /Users/simon/Documents/Documents.mhl', '>', text_report]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking the OS to run the executable `'mhl verify -vv -f'`, and there is no such executable. No shell splitting takes place on the spaces there.

With `shell=True` you'd want to pass in everything as *one string*, not as separate arguments:

```
sub.Popen('mhl verify -vv -f {} > {}'.format(item, text_report),
          shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
```

Note that there is little point in directing `stdout` to a pipe here, since all stdout output from the `mhl` command is being redirected to a file.

If you wanted to capture the output of the `mhl` command directly in Python, I'd not use a shell intermediary here; run without `shell=True` and then just use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to retrieve the output:

```
output = sub.check_output(['mhl', 'verify', '-vv', '-f', item])
```

Note that now the program name and the arguments must be passed in ready-split into separate strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work, as with the original code only the 'mhl' argument is recognized, it tells me 'invalid number of arguments'.  Actually `mhl verify -vv -f` is recognized properly as a call to the mhl executable with the 'verify -vv -f' arguments, but it tells me a mhl file should follow the '-f' argument.

Comment: @SimonTheChain: you also pass in `item`, `>` and `text_report`.

Comment: @SimonTheChain: updated; I missed that you did have `shell=True` set. You still have a command `mhl verify -vv -f item` being executed here.

Comment: Just saw your update, I'll look into capturing the output differently, thanks again.